# “Keep watch for”

Tags: grammar, phrases, editing

Is the following sentence correct?

> Hotel staff must diligently **keep watch for** durians because...

I am not sure whether to use “keep watch for” or “keep watch on” or any other phrase. Could anyone help me choose the correct phrase? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you want to express. Please [edit] to include a description of what you want the phrase to say.

Comment: I understand that the durian is a fruit with a strong smell. I think it would be more appropriate to say something like 'keep watch for guests bringing durians in', as the fruit can't creep into the hotel on their own!

Comment: @KateBunting They just smell as though they could (so I understand)!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!